# Bootstrap fixed size right column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using bootstrap v. 2.3.2 (ie7 reason), and would like to make a grid with one fixed column size (300px). I can do this when that col is first and in left column but I need it in the right side of page. I also found on stack some working examples, but in this examples the fixed column is first in page code and then floated to the right. Is it possible to make layoud where `span300px` will be the "last" and fixed size element (semantic reason)?

My code is very simple:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8">
          ....
        </div>
        <div class="span300px">
          ....
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When page will be displayed on smart-phone, that column will be hidden.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add custom class to your span.

html :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
        <div>
          ....
        </div>
        <div class="span3 fixed300">
          ....
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
fixed300 {
    min-width:300px !important;
    max-width:300px !important;
    float:right !important;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately width of column is taken from span3, and in this example whole site has now only 11 column.

Comment: Can you try with '!important' like in my edit, and ... i'm coding on a 11 columns too ;)

Comment: now the right column has 300px but the `span8` column is not fluid?? I have 50px "margin" betwen

Comment: Than the whole column have 100% and right column is moving down

Comment: If you put 100%, normal that it takes 100% of width... you fix a column at 300px. In my project : left column has no class and right column (span3 is fixed to 300px). You shouldn't put 100%, the left column is automaticly fix to the right width [for me].......